# What does feature mean in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, features

I can't understand the meaning of feature in QGIS [`QgsFeature`](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html) class. How it is related to layer and geometry?

I have read QGIS documentation but I can't understand what is feature.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Notwithstanding whether there are non-geographical features, I think of a feature as being something with geometry (x,y etc) and attributes i.e. a feature is more than geometry.  Then when a feature (as part of a feature class) is displayed on a map it also has symbology (points drawn in red dots of 10pts, etc) and can be referred to as part of a layer.

In other words, glossing over many details:

- feature = geometry + attributes
- feature class = collection of features
- layer = feature class + symbology

Answer (score 0):

A feature means geographic feature  (has geometry). Consequently, if it doesn't have geometry, it's not a feature.

Comment: Not necessarily: [What is a non-geographical feature?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/68651/753)