# Creating connections between multiple points from CSV file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, import, polyline-creation, points-to-line

I have the following situation:

I have two CSV files: One file lists all nodes and their longitude and latitude in the following manner with the following columns:

| ID | Name | Longitude | Latitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

No importing these points into QGIS is no problem. However, I would now like to import a second CSV to connect these points. That CSV has the following columns

| Connection ID | From | To | To | To | To | To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I give each connection an ID and then under `"From"` and `"To"` I put the `"ID"` that corresponds to the nodes in the first CSV files. Importantly, these connections usually have more than two points (thus the several `"To"` columns).

Is there an easy way of creating these connections (lines) between the points in the first CSV? And is it possible to do it with the second CSV files I am using, most importantly in terms of having multiple points for each connection?

I know that certain plugins ("PointstoPaths") can be used for this, but I am using QGIS Firenze and have not been able to find a suitable plugin that works with this version.

Comment: From a ease of handling perspective you would be better with connection table |id|from|to|. At the very least all field names need to be unique such as ||Connection ID|From|To1|To2|To3|To4|   Are all "to?" always non null? One feature per 'connection id' or just one feature per 'from' 'to?'?

Comment: Okay thanks. I hope I understand what you mean: No, in certain cases "to" is empty. Can I ask what you mean by "feature"?

Comment: Does the answer in this question help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141078/generating-line-segments-between-all-points-using-qgis ?

Comment: A tldr for what a [qgis feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75332/what-does-feature-mean-in-qgis) is, might be one row of a layer. The linked stack exchange has a decent answer.

Comment: `Points to path` is available in QGIS 3.28 Firenze, its not a plugin: Menu Processing > Toolbox > Points to path: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgispointstopath You must make sure you load the CSV in a way to create points

Comment: By the way: sharing your csv files and showing a screenshot with how you want the result to look like would help a lot to understand what to intend to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

I created a CSV file, with columns with the same name and then I load it in QGIS. What QGIS does is to add a consecutive suffix separated by an underscore in the repeated fields (e.j. To, To_1, To_2, ...). So every "To" field name has the form `To_#`.

Try this, open the **"Geometry by expression"** tool, set the output geometry type to the line and use this expression. Remember to change the node layer name/id in the expression.

```sql
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach(
        array_filter(
            map_akeys(attributes($currentfeature)),
            regexp_match(
                @element,
                '^To_[0-9]+$'
            )
            AND
            NOT attribute(@element) IS NULL
        ),
        make_line(
            geometry(
                get_feature(
                    'Point layer name/id', --replace here with your values
                    'ID',
                    attribute(@element)
                )
            ),
            geometry(
                get_feature(
                    'Point layer name/id', --replace here with your values
                    'ID',
                    attribute('From')
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Then use the **"Multipart to singleparts"** tool to separate each different line, because the geometry generator will generate a multipart geometry in this case.